# How to fix the code for Subtaction, multiplication and division C#

Tags: c#

I'm Making a Calculator. I have created the code when I input two numbers and press equal it does its job such as subtracting, adding, multiplying and dividing. help me to make the code for subtracting, multiplying and dividing continuously without pressing equal for addition i have done the code please help me for the buttons. I will include the whole code below please help me fix it.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Windows10Calcoo : Form
    {
        string Input, NumStore1, NumStore2 = string.Empty ;
        char Operation;
        double Answ;
        public Windows10Calcoo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void PlusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Creating + and Storing Num1
        NumStore1 = Input;
        Operation = '+';
        Input = string.Empty;

        //Storing Number 2
        NumStore2 = Input;
        double num1, num2;
        double.TryParse(NumStore1, out num1);
        double.TryParse(NumStore2, out num2);

        // Adding Code
        Answ += num1 + num2;
        textBox1.Text = Answ.ToString();



    }

    private void SubBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumStore1 = Input;
        Operation = '-';
        Input = string.Empty;

        //Storing Number 2
        NumStore2 = Input;
        double num1, num2;
        double.TryParse(NumStore1, out num1);
        double.TryParse(NumStore2, out num2);

        // Adding Code
        Answ += num1 - num2 ;
        textBox1.Text = Answ.ToString();
    }

    private void DivideBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumStore1 = Input;
        Operation = '/';
        Input = string.Empty;

    }

    private void MultiBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumStore1 = Input;
        Operation = '*';
        Input = string.Empty;

    }

    private void BackSpaceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int textlength = textBox1.Text.Length;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textlength - 1);
    }

    private void OneBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "1";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void TwoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "2";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void ThreeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "3";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void FourBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "4";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void FiveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "5";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void SixBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "6";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void SevenBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "7";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void EightBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "8";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void NineBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "9";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void ZeroBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += "0";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void DecimalBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        Input += ".";
        this.textBox1.Text += Input;
    }

    private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Input += "C";

        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        this.Input = string.Empty;
        this.NumStore1 = string.Empty;
        this.NumStore2 = string.Empty;
        Answ = 0;

    }

    private void EqualBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NumStore2 = Input;
        double num1, num2;
        double.TryParse(NumStore1, out num1);
        double.TryParse(NumStore2, out num2);


        this.textBox1.Text = "";
        this.Input = string.Empty;
        this.NumStore1 = string.Empty;
        this.NumStore2 = string.Empty;

        if (Operation == '+')
        {
            Answ = num1 + num2;
            textBox1.Text = Answ.ToString();
        }
        else if (Operation == '-')
        {
            Answ = num1 - num2;
            textBox1.Text = Answ.ToString();
        }
        else if (Operation == '*')
        {
            Answ = num1 * num2;
            textBox1.Text = Answ.ToString();
        }
        else if (Operation == '/')
        {
            if (num2 != 0)
            {
                Answ = num1 / num2;
                textBox1.Text = Answ.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "DIV/Zero!";
            }
        }

    }
    private void Windows10Calcoo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

for subtraction button its not subtracting sits continuesly adding when i use [Answ += num1 - num2 ;], if i use [Answ -= num1 - num2 ;] its adding negatively .

Comment: *it's adding negatively* isn't that subtracting? do you want to present only the action on the two numbers or keep history of the actions? in that case if `num1` is bigger than `num2` `Answ` will increase.

Comment: no i mean "100 - 50 = 50" but i get the answer "-50" and if I subtract it with "5" it changes into "+55" then again i subtract it with "5"  it changes into "-50", thank toy for replying @Guy